# Why do we square the error in cost function of Machine Learning models?

Tags: machine-learning

What would happen if we don't square the error of the cost function?

For example in logistic regression we square the cost function.

Comment: Did you try doing a web search for answers? Looks like a duplicate of [Why do cost functions use the square error](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10188/why-do-cost-functions-use-the-square-error), which seems to have some detailed answers for this question.

Comment: Yes, posted this question impulsively, and cannot remove since people have provided an answer. Will be careful next time, on not to post a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with logistic regression, as I'm more of a deep learning guy, but I'll take a crack at your question.
First off, we need to specify some things. What cost function are you talking about and for which machine learning model are you using it? Within each discipline of machine learning, there are tons of suitable error functions depending on the problem, and they can be either squared or not squared.

You mentioned squaring values in logistic regression... but there are many pros and cons to using a sum of squares vs. an MLE model, discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy). For an example in another topic, there exist neural network cost functions that square values ([MSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error)), as well as ones that don't ([Cross Entropy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/254067/173038.)).
Regardless, there are some common themes that describe when it is appropriate to square values in a cost function. As a (very) general rule, you want to square your variables when they are continuous and have a definable distance metric.

Let's say I'm trying to predict points on the number line. If I predict values `y_predicted`, and compare them to `y_true`, then I know exactly how far I am in terms of that 1D distance. That is a continuous error metric, which means that I don't want to lose information by discretizing it. Furthermore, putting a square in there means that I avoid dealing with positive and negative values that could cancel each other out during a summation. Lastly, squaring values emphasizes the outliers, while slightly neglecting smaller errors, which can be helpful in certain situations.
Long story short, it depends on the scope of your problem. Wish there was an easier solution, but that's just how it goes.

Comment: Frankly, your answer needs another answer to explain it! What is `continuous error metric` and What is `outliers`?!

Comment: Continuous vs. discrete is the mathematical equivalent of floats vs. ints in computer science. Continuous metrics can have any number, discrete ones will only fall into specific buckets.

Outliers are data samples that are more outside of the usual data distribution than the average samples. If these topics are new to you, then I would recommend taking a statistics course, as it will be very helpful before diving into machine learning/probabilistic modeling.

Comment: I did take a statistic course in college, nevertheless, simple English accompanied with what you wrote would deliver the info better, ... better than writing fancy words abstractly! Delivering the information uniquely is quite different from knowing (even mastering) them!
BTW, some people need refresher that if your answers included them, you would have got more upvotes (i.e. appreciations).